# docker compose access denied to aws yet docker itself is ok

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, docker-compose

I am logged in into AWS using AWS-CLI and pushing the images to ECR using docker commands like so works fine:

`docker push xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.dkr.ecr.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/mytryoutapplication.server`

Now I have a docker-compose file that looks like this

```
services:
  api:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.dkr.ecr.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/dockerfile.server
    image: docker.server
  client:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.dkr.ecr.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/dockerfile.client
    image: docker.client
    ports:
      - "3000:80"
```

pushing these images separately with the docker commands works as intended to AWS but when I do `docker compose push` I get this

[image]

am I missing some configuration that I am unaware of?
I have been looking for hours now but cannot seem to find a fix for it.
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

`docker compose push` is going to try and use the image names you have specified in the `compose.yaml` file.

There, you have specified `docker.server` as the image for the server process, which will make docker add `registry.docker.io/library/` and try to push to docker hub.

A common practice is to use an environment variable so you can push to specific repos, but still use a simple image name most of the time:

```yaml
services:
  server:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}mytryoutapplication.server
```

and then you can

```bash
DOCKER_REGISTRY=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.dkr.ecr.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/ docker compose push
```

Comment: This is the same result as I already have with access denied. There is no difference in having the environment variable set like that or hardcoding it directly into the yaml file.